# Wipe out Local git commit without affect code

Tags: git, android-studio, github

How does one delete a local git commit without affecting code.

I did a commit but it will not push because a file exceeds GitHubs 100MB limit.  When prevents the commit from being pushed, and all subsequent commits.

I have removed the offending file, but the commit still has it as part of the commit.

I have since done other commits (which I can lose). But I can't lose the code as it stands now.

Thanks all

Comment: You can't cancel commit like revert it ?

Comment: @Elikill58 Revert does not remove files, so if a file in a commit is too big for github, revert is not the answer.

Comment: Is it the very last commit on your current branch? If it is, can't you delete the file on disk, do `git add .`, then `git commit --amend` to update the last commit?

Comment: yes but if you go to old commit, then do another one which replace the too big commit, maybe it can works

Comment: I have manually already removed the file.  Never heard of revert before.  Also Lasse, sadly no it's not the last commit, but I don't mind losing all commits as long as it doesn't change/affect a code file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 0):

> I have removed the offending file, but the commit still has it as part of the commit.

This is a job for `git rebase`. Specifically, I think you want the `-i` interactive option, which allows you to remove one or more commits in the history, reorder commits, edit individual commits, etc. For example, you could:

```
git log
```

to see the commits;

```
git rebase -i <hash of the commit prior to adding the big file>
```

to start the rebase process. This will open an editor and show you a list of commits back to the one you specified, along with commands for each. It's a powerful tool and you should read more extensive instructions than I'm giving here, but for example you could edit the commit where you added the big file by changing `pick` for that commit to `edit`. `git rebase` will then replay the commits, stopping on the commit you want to edit. You can delete the file and 'git add' it, and then `git rebase continue` to replay the rest of the commits. After that, the file should have been removed from the history.

**The standard warning applies:** `rebase` is a powerful command that can really screw up your git history, so be very careful with it. When in doubt, make a copy of your branch beforehand so that you can get back to your current state.